# Should I be suspicious of this querystring?

Tags: asp.net, hacking, query

I noticed in my application event log some errors:

`Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client (term="DT&#304;NST32")`

`Request URL: http://domain.com/url.aspx?term=DTNT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE%233043/6/2010 6:41:33 PMBNST32`

What is this kind of request trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "DTİNST32" is actually referring to  dpinst32.exe which is a driver.

So IMHO, the log entry is fine. But you may want to check the device settings and try to update the driver.

You may want to see [this document](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F5%2Fd%2F6%2F5d6eaf2b-7ddf-476b-93dc-7cf0072878e6%2F32-64bit_install.docx&ei=sBmTS8PKBNff8AaliuD2BA&usg=AFQjCNGf7-3ID0cLiGQp7gG7Ae796E8-Zw&sig2=l9sqyIscCbuc_eFxxuSitA) from Microsoft discussing driver installation for 32-bit and 64-bit platforms

Rich